# Apache, NodeJS and socket.io: Use Apache or NodeJS as Reverse-Proxy?

Tags: apache, node.js, proxy, socket.io, reverse

I have an Apache-Server running my PHP-Application on Port 80. The PHP-Application communicates with the NodeJS-Server (socket.io) over Port 3000.

Due to firewall restrictions, I should only use Port 80. Therefore I need to specify an url like /nodejs/ that is reversed internally on the server to port 3000 (NodeJS).

Is it better (in respect of performance) to use Apache (mod_proxy) as Reverse-Proxy to forward NodeJS-Data to NodeJS or is it better to do that on NodeJS (e.g. with https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) and therefore let NodeJS running on Port 80 and forward all non-NodeJS-Data internally to Apache (which then would run on another port)?

I probably have a bit more socket.io calls than normal HTTP-Requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need proxying, you should use something like HAProxy, which is designed specifically for that.

Apache is not that good at proxying, because it has to fork or start a new thread for each connection (thus loosing all the benefit of Node).

Further than that, I wouldn't use Apache at all if I needed to optimize things, NGINX is much better as a server (it's even faster than Node.js for serving static files for example).

If you're looking for Node.js proxy solutions HTTP-Proxy and Bouncy are the best:

- https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy
- http://substack.net/posts/5bd18d

Resources:

- http://haproxy.1wt.eu/
- http://arstechnica.com/business/2011/11/a-faster-web-server-ripping-out-apache-for-nginx/

Comment: Thanks. I did it with node-http-proxy with a routing table:

`var options = {
  router: {
    'localhost': '127.0.0.1:8000',
    'localhost/nodejs': '127.0.0.1:3000'
  }
};

httpProxy.createServer(options).listen(80);`